# Find and update duplicate values held in a column with a unique constraint? - Msg 402 The data types are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, unique-constraint, database-cursor

I need to create a SQL Server query to clean up an old database by ensuring all non-unique values in columns with a unique restraint are updated to be unique.

To do this I was thinking to find all columns in the database that have a unique constraint. Then go through all the values in those columns to find any non-unique values. Lastly, thinking to add a suffix to the end of any non-unique values. When the suffix is used it will increment by 1.

For all duplicates, the table, column, old non-unique value, and new unique value need to be written to the console.

To me, it seemed like I would need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Is there a better way?

This is what I currently have:

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE uniqueColumns CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    cu.TABLE_NAME,
    cu.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'

OPEN uniqueColumns

FETCH NEXT FROM uniqueColumns INTO @tableName, @columnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'
        WITH DuplicatesCTE AS (
            SELECT                
                ColumnNameString AS ColumnName,
                ColumnNameString AS OriginalValue,
                ColumnNameString + ''_'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnNameString ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewValue
            FROM TableNameString
            WHERE ColumnNameString IN (
                SELECT ColumnNameString
                FROM TableNameString
                GROUP BY ColumnNameString
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            )
        )
        UPDATE DuplicatesCTE
        SET OriginalValue = NewValue
        OUTPUT INSERTED.ColumnName, INSERTED.NewValue
    ';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, 'TableNameString', QUOTENAME(@tableName))
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, 'ColumnNameString', QUOTENAME(@columnName))

    --EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    PRINT @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM uniqueColumns INTO @tableName, @columnName
END

CLOSE uniqueColumns
DEALLOCATE uniqueColumns
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
> The data types uniqueidentifier and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

If I print the `@sql` instead of executing it I get this SQL:

```
WITH DuplicatesCTE AS (
    SELECT                
        [AdminRoleId] AS ColumnName,
        [AdminRoleId] AS OriginalValue,
        [AdminRoleId] + '_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [AdminRoleId] ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NewValue
    FROM [AdminRoleModules]
    WHERE [AdminRoleId] IN (
        SELECT [AdminRoleId]
        FROM [AdminRoleModules]
        GROUP BY [AdminRoleId]
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
)
UPDATE DuplicatesCTE
SET OriginalValue = NewValue
```

And I get the same error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> The data types uniqueidentifier and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: I believe you need to text-quote the values the values you are capturing in your CTE - Instead of `[TableName] AS TableName`, you need `''[TableName]'' AS TableName`.  The generated SQL would be like `'[table1]' AS TableName`.  Safer would be to move the string quoting to the substition logic. Change `[TableName] AS TableName` to `[TableNameString] AS TableName` and add `REPLACE(@sql, '[TableNameString]', QUOTENAME(@tableName, ''''))`. This would yield `'table1' AS TableName`. Repeat as needed for other substitutions. Note that cases like `[ColumnName] AS OriginalValue` would not change.

Comment: Also worth noting that the command `ALTER TABLE <tablename> WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT <constraint name>;` can be used to validate (and enable?) existing constraints.  (I think I have that right.) But if you already know you have duplicates, I think the dynamic SQL is a reasonable approach. (Someone else may chime in with a better suggestion.)

Comment: If you haven't already done so, try printing the generated SQL instead of executing it. Then cut and paste it into a new window and test its execution there. It may be easier to find the offending code there.

Comment: Adding designators like "String" to the replacements is a good idea to keep clarity. I have done that and added the quotes you suggested. I still get the same error.

Comment: I think it's `OUTPUT INSERTED.TableName, INSERTED.ColumnName, INSERTED.NewValue`. Try `OUTPUT [TableNameString] AS TableName, [ColumnNameString] AS ColumnName, INSERTED.OriginalValue AS NewValue`.  (The last item is tricky. `OriginalValue` is the alias assigned in the CTE to the column you are updating.)  And would you also want to capture the *original* `DELETED.OriginalValue`?

Comment: If there are unique constraints in place, how are there duplicates? i.e. I don't see the point of a cursor based on unique constraints designed to test for duplicates.

Comment: `AdminRoleId` is a `uniqueidentifier` and you can't create a new valid  `uniqueidentifier`  by appending a string suffix to that. But anyway unless you answer Adrian's point the whole exercise seems pointless

Comment: There are duplicates because as mentioned previous, it is an old database that needs to be cleaned up (over 20 years old). My guess is that the constraints did not exist at one point.

Comment: You would not have been able to alter the table to add a unique key if there were duplicates..You should clarify by adding table definitions, sample data and desired outcome as text, being clear what you mean by a duplicate

Comment: It is not possible to add a unique constraint unless the data is unique. There is no equivalent of `NOCHECK` for these

Comment: If your current query is doing anything at all then presumably it is incorrectly enforcing uniqueness on single columns where the constraint is multi column

Comment: As the OP stated earlier, he inherited an old database and I presume is in the process of cleaning it up. If there are any UNIQUE indexes present, they are presumably in a disabled state.  The OP is trying to eliminate the duplicates so that the unique indexes can be re-enabled, restoring data integrity.  See [this storyboard](https://dbfiddle.uk/0Pzdlbs5). (I was initially thinking in terms of unique constraints, but as far as I can tell, those cannot be disabled, only deleted.)

Comment: @TN - I doubt it. Leaving indexes lying around in a disabled state is extremely unusual (and undesirable) - my money is that they have misinterpreted compound indexes as their code in the self answer takes no account of these and tries to apply uniqueness to any `NVARCHAR` column for a `UNIQUE` index in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE`

Comment: @MartinSmith - Got it. I missed the fact the the query above was pulling from TABLE_CONSTRAINTS. (I was working from past experience where I have found databases with scattered disabled FK constraints and has to restore them to health. I though unique constraints could be similarly disabled, until I discovered they specifically cannot be disabled. That led me to thinking maybe "unique indexes". I got too far off the path.)  In any case, my main point is that the OP inherited a database that needs fixing, and are working to accomplish that task.

Comment: @TysonGibby - Did you see my "I think it's `OUTPUT...`" comment I posted above? I think that would solve your data capture issue, or at least put you on the path towards ding so.  Also my suggestion to use `[TableNameString]` and `[ColumnNameString]` was intended to be *in addition to* the `[TableName]` and `[ColumnName]` substitutions that you already had. Use TableName and ColumnName when you need to access the actual table or column in the generated SQL. Use TableNameString and ColumnNameString when you want to capture the name of the table or column as a string in your output.

Comment: @TN - But my main point is that they may think they "inherited a database that needs fixing, and are working to accomplish that task" but as it currently stands it looks like they may be seeing a problem where there isn't one. And "fixing" something that doesn't need fixing and doing harm in the process

Comment: Doh! Now I got it. The OP thinks they have dups and are using the defined unique constraints to seek them out, but the presence of those same unique constraints guarantees that there are none. Also a multi-column unique constraint does not imply that the referenced individual columns *are* or *should be* unique, only that the tuples are unique, so trying to "fix" those columns is unnecessary.  @TysonGibby - did you get that?

Comment: I appreciate all of your insights and expertise.  I have worked on multiple 20+ year old databases with these same issues. Not sure why or how these issues happened over the years, but they did. On this project we have been tasked to fix the issues, so we are.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there were several syntax errors in my dynamic SQL. In addition, I had forgotten to run this on strings only, not on Primary Keys or Foreign Keys. These issues have been fixed in the below SQL:

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE uniqueColumns CURSOR FOR
SELECT
    cu.TABLE_NAME,
    cu.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col ON cu.COLUMN_NAME = col.COLUMN_NAME AND cu.TABLE_NAME = col.TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
    AND col.DATA_TYPE = 'NVARCHAR'

OPEN uniqueColumns

FETCH NEXT FROM uniqueColumns INTO @tableName, @columnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'
        WITH DuplicatesCTE AS (
            SELECT                
                ColumnNameString AS ColumnName,
                ColumnNameString AS OriginalValue,
                (ColumnNameString + ''_'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnNameString ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS NewValue
            FROM TableNameString
            WHERE ColumnNameString IN (
                SELECT ColumnNameString
                FROM TableNameString
                GROUP BY ColumnNameString
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            )
        )
        UPDATE DuplicatesCTE
        SET OriginalValue = NewValue
        OUTPUT INSERTED.ColumnName--, INSERTED.NewValue
    ';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, 'TableNameString', QUOTENAME(@tableName))
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, 'ColumnNameString', QUOTENAME(@columnName))

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    --PRINT @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM uniqueColumns INTO @tableName, @columnName
END

CLOSE uniqueColumns
DEALLOCATE uniqueColumns
```

This however still falls short in outputting the table name, column name, old value, and new value so the changes can be audited. It is also too broad in it's scope of changes as well.  Currently we are moving toward creating a query that is a report only. This way we can identify the tables and columns that need cleaning up. Then we will address those individually. I will update this answer when I have the full solution.